# Horizontal sticky header on top of items in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need sticky header overlay in start and over items in horizontal recyclerview.

To obtain results I try text view inside item and hide/unhide for header purpose. That work's fine for header but can't make it sticky.

Now using https://github.com/fabionuno/Timehop.StickyHeadersRecyclerView

I have change `StickyRecyclerHeadersDecoration` class and I am getting following result

[image]
Code:

```
public class StickyRecyclerHeadersDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

  private final StickyRecyclerHeadersAdapter mAdapter;
  private final ItemVisibilityAdapter mVisibilityAdapter;
  private final SparseArray<Rect> mHeaderRects = new SparseArray<>();
  private final HeaderProvider mHeaderProvider;
  private final OrientationProvider mOrientationProvider;
  private final HeaderPositionCalculator mHeaderPositionCalculator;
  private final HeaderRenderer mRenderer;
  private final DimensionCalculator mDimensionCalculator;

  ...

  /**
   * Sets the offsets for the first item in a section to make room for the header view
   *
   * @param itemOffsets rectangle to define offsets for the item
   * @param header      view used to calculate offset for the item
   * @param orientation used to calculate offset for the item
   */
  private void setItemOffsetsForHeader(Rect itemOffsets, View header, int orientation) {
    mDimensionCalculator.initMargins(mTempRect, header);
    if (orientation == LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL) {
      mTempRect.top = -header.getHeight();
      itemOffsets.top = 0;
      itemOffsets.bottom = 1;
//      itemOffsets.top = header.getHeight() + mTempRect.top + mTempRect.bottom;
//      itemOffsets.top = 0;
    } else {
      mTempRect.left = -header.getWidth();
      itemOffsets.left = 0;
      itemOffsets.right = 1;
//      itemOffsets.left = header.getWidth() + mTempRect.left + mTempRect.right;
//      itemOffsets.left = 0;
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Required view:
[image]

As you notice from two snaps there is problem with my `StickyRecyclerHeadersDecoration` drawing. Header 'C' should be over and start of item 'Caiman'

How can I solve this problem.
Referring to any other library that meet my app design requirements is ok too.

Thanks

Note: I will remove that half transparent blue color from header background for my app.

Comment: Did you got a solution for this? I am also looking for the same.

Comment: I think I solve that with same `StickyRecyclerHeadersDecoration` but I have to check

Comment: Please check. It would be great if you could post the solution.

Comment: Any news on that @Qamar I really want to find an answer to that as well.